# Converting Dictionary to list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, csv, attributeerror

I am a beginner in Python and I am  trying to solve a chinese-postman problem and following [this tutorial](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/intro-to-graph-optimization-solving-cpp/#motivating-graph-optimization).

I am on the step: *Computing minimum weight matching*.
I need to convert the dictionary to a list of tuples

The code below is what I have so far

```
# Compute min weight matching.
# Note: max_weight_matching uses the 'weight' attribute by default as the attribute to maximize.
odd_matching_dupes = nx.algorithms.max_weight_matching(g_odd_complete, True)

print('Number of edges in matching: {}'.format(len(odd_matching_dupes)))

# Preview of matching with dupes
odd_matching_dupes

# Convert matching to list of deduped tuples
odd_matching = list(pd.unique([tuple(sorted([k, v])) for k, v in 
odd_matching_dupes.items()]))
```

---

The output I get for `odd_matching_dupes` is:

```
{('rep1', 'rep2'),
('rep12', 'rep16'),
('rep17', 'rep13'),
('rep27', 'rep19'),
('rep7', 'rep10'),
('rep8', 'rep5')}
```

---

This is the error message that I get:

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-7da9b4bbe8a5> in <module>
142 
143 # Convert matching to list of deduped tuples
--> 144 odd_matching = list(pd.unique([tuple(sorted([k, v])) for k, v in 
odd_matching_dupes.items()]))

AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: `odd_matching_dupes` is a `set()` Object. `.items()` works with `dict`

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the output when you print `odd_matching_dupes`?

Comment: @sophros the output I get is this
     {('rep1', 'rep2'),
     ('rep12', 'rep16'),
     ('rep17', 'rep13'),
     ('rep27', 'rep19'),
     ('rep7', 'rep10'),
     ('rep8', 'rep5')}
as seen like how I added above

Comment: @Rakesh hi, could I possible ask as to how I should change my code to make it work?

Comment: @ElizabethDC: replace `odd_matching_dupes.items()` by `odd_matching_dupes` and you're good to go